# PHP - Reconnect to mySQL again or send previous via POST?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, post

I have two web pages: page1.php and page2.php.

**In page1.php**

There is a mySQL query executed and saved into variable A.

**In page2.php**

I want the same results of the same query.

Should I reconnect to mySQL and execute the query again **or** send the variable A from page1.php via POST or SESSION? What is the fast solution? There is any other solution?

**EDIT:** There is no other queries, so the data will not change (I think)

Comment: How do you ensure that the data passed from page1 to page2 hasn't been tampered with in any way? How can you trust the data? You could use $_SESSIONS to store the data but I don't believe there's an issue in running the query again

Comment: There is no other mysql queries, so I thnik the data will not change .(I will I add to my post that the data base will not change between page1 and page2.). I m just looking for fast way that will not increase the time of page charging

Comment: It would probably be _faster_ to just pass the result from the query to page 2, otherwise you are hitting your database twice for the same query within seconds of eachother.

Comment: Session is faster than mysql if your data does'nt change

Comment: I certainly wouldn't pass it via POST, this allows for the data to be tampered with by a malicious client. SESSION will be a bit faster assuming the dataset is not too large, and is unlikely to change in the space of a user's session. Unless your query is quite long-running though, we are potentially talking about only fractions of a second difference. It would be useful to know how long your query actually takes normally. Another design note: if you want exactly the same results on multiple pages, consider a 3rd script you can include in the others which does nothing but produce that output

Comment: then you don't repeat the same UI and database code twice.

Comment: The script will reconnect to database every time? @ADyson

Comment: yes. It's more about saving duplication of the actual written code, so it's easier for you to debug and maintain. Just the basic DRY principle (Do not Repeat Yourself) which should apply to all programming wherever possible. Like I said above, if you're concerned about the performance of the query being run multiple times then use sessions to store the data. How long does the query take, normally?

Comment: I do not know the time that takes, BUT It's a ` SELECT * FROM TABLE ` with 14 000 rows. @ADyson

Comment: you must be able to measure how long it takes quite easily?? If it's just a select from one table I can't imagine it takes very long. On the other hand, 14000 rows is really quite a lot to be storing in the session. If you have a lot of users, you would have to keep an eye on how much memory on your server it is consuming.

Comment: That's very useful!  I will use the DRY script. Thank you @ADyson (you can copy this into answer if you want me to vote )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't pass it via POST, this allows for the data to be tampered with by a malicious client.

SESSION will be a bit faster assuming the dataset is not too large, and if the data is unlikely to change in the space of a user's session it's a reasoble choice.

It would be useful to know how long your query actually takes normally, to see whether the time difference would be significant. You did mention that the result set contains 14000 rows. If it's just a select from one table I can't imagine it takes very long. 14000 rows is really quite a lot to be storing in the session. Remember that it stores the dataset once for every user using the site at any one moment (since a session is specific to a single user). If you have a lot of users, you would have to keep an eye on how much memory on your server it is consuming.

Another design note: if you want exactly the same results on multiple pages, consider a 3rd script you can include in the others which does nothing but produce that output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not shure if the data may have changed, make a new query! It may take some more time to do this operation but you can be sure the data is still up to date.
What if the user restarts page1.php in another browser while still processing page2.php?
So only if you are 100% sure nothing can be manipulated or if loading the data takes too much time/resources reuse the data.

Never trust data which may have been changed by the user and ALWAYS make sure the still is what you expect it is. Maybe you should consider to make some kind of validation of the data.